# Kafka Producer: Understanding `retries` config param

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka Documentation for Producer Config parameter `retries` says that retry will happen for potentially transient errors.

> [Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error. Allowing retries without setting max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to 1 will potentially change the ordering of records because if two batches are sent to a single partition, and the first fails and is retried but the second succeeds, then the records in the second batch may appear first.](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#producerconfigs)

1. What are these ***potentially transient errors***? What scenarios cause these 'transient errors'?
2. In the source code, I see that there is a `RetriableException` Interface and `TimeoutException` implements it. But I have observed that retry does not happen for every timeout exception thrown by `send(ProducerRecord<K,V> record)` method of `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer`. So, what I am missing here ... Aren't all `RetriableException` retried when `retries` param is greater than 0?

Comment: Exceptions thrown by send are different to ones handled by retry. Producer client does actual sending in a separate background thread, and carries out retries without the thread that called send knowing about it. If retries are successful them send only finds out about success (if it waits for the asynchronous outcome). If retries are exhausted then there is an asynchronous failure response. Send will synchronously get an exception if the send buffer has filled up so there is no space to add any more messages (eg if all pending messages are being retried)

Comment: Not sure if the above helps but I think it is relevant to your question.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for that insight. Do you know then how i can verify if retries are happening...would that be logged in `server.log` or some other file?

Comment: Hi, server end wouldn't know about retries, it would be in client logs - maybe bump up the log level

Comment: Is there a specific Exception when the retries exceeds the configured limit?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "potentially transient" and "permanent" errors it's quite simple.

Potentially transient ones are temporary errors that have a chance of resolving automatically within reasonable time: connection errors, temporary states (no leader for partition), etc.

Permanent errors on the other hand are the ones that cannot be resolved with retries and most likely require a manual intervention: e.g. if a topic does not exist and is not auto-created then it'll require some external entity (such as a human) to create it.

You can find which errors are retriable for example here: https://kafka.apache.org/25/generated/protocol_errors.html

Regarding the retires in the producer code, it looks like they are done on a different level.
If you trace the usage of `RETRIES_CONFIG` you'll see that `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer` passes that to create a `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender` which is actually "The background thread that handles the sending of produce requests to the Kafka cluster." It has the `canRetry()` method where the decision is made whether to retry the send or not.